# C#: в чем разница между readonly и const?

Tags: c#, const, readonly

Привет всем!
В C# есть const и readonly.
В сети нашел только информацию о разнице static readonly и const. А какая разница между просто readonly и const?

Comment: Плохо искали: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly

Comment: Если проще ответ вверху, то readonly можно менять в конструкторе

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Значения полей с модификатором `const` при компиляции подставляются в тех местах кода, где к ним происходит обращение. Это значит, что в случае, когда такое поле объявлено в классе одной сборки, а используется классами другой сборки, для того чтобы измененное значение было применено в зависимой сборке, потребуется перекомпиляция зависимой сборки.  Задать значение можно только в момент объявления. В общем то `const`-поля это не совсем поля.

Поля с модификатором `readonly` являются полноценными полями, с той разницей, что изменять их значение разрешено только в конструкторе. Соответственно `static readonly` - в статическом конструкторе (код инициализации полей при объявлении переносится в конструктор компилятором). Таким образом, значения `readonly`-полей могут, например вычисляться на основе параметров переданных в конструктор, что невозможно для `const`-полей.

В большинстве случаев рекомендуется использовать именно `readonly`-поля вместо `const`-полей когда ваш проект включает более одного модуля.

А еще у нас тут есть шикарный [список литературы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/198316) рекомендуемой к прочтению для изучения C# и .NET. Книги в списке условно разделены по уровню сложности. Большую часть из них можно найти в сети в электронном виде, было бы желание. Так уж получается, что без чтения книжек программисту не обойтись.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Можете показать как переопределить статический конструктор (я хотел бы детальнее посмотреть как оно работает)?

Comment: @Alerr не понял, зачем его переопределять, он не наследуется, он просто создается компилятором если вы его не создали сами. А если создали, то помещает в его начало код инциализации статических полей.

Comment: посоветуйте книжку по C#, которую считаете адекватной

Comment: @Alerr собственно из предложенного списка Тролсен, затем Рихтер, а дальше уже сами поймете чего не хватает, но это лично мое мнение.

Comment: @Alerr из Тролсена обязательны первые 4 части, остальное по желанию и необходимости, после этого можно переключаться на Рихтера. Рихтера целиком с компилятором под руками от корки до корки =)